# Python Pandas Check if Value in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For anybody that has any experience with Python and Pandas,

I am trying to compare two dataframes (not equal indices) and see if one value from a column (studentIDs) is in another dataframe with the same column name.

If it is not, I need to add it to a separate dataframe.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: there are a few questions on this on StackOverflow already. most of them involve some form of [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: Thank you I guess I will attempt the question that is supposed to be the same answer to mine.